# Possible to add multiple approveDelegateAuthority() in the same transaction?

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js

I am trying to approve delegation of multiple NFTs without having multiple transactions. Is this possible with the metaplex js library? Here is the code:

```
await this.metaplex.tokens().approveDelegateAuthority({
  mintAddress: nftMint,
  //@ts-ignore
  delegateAuthority: this.publicKey,
});
```

I am looking for a way to have something like this:

```
const delegatenft1 = this.metaplex.tokens().approveDelegateAuthority({
  mintAddress: nftMint,
  //@ts-ignore
  delegateAuthority: this.publicKey,
});

const transaction = new Transaction().add(delegatenft1, delegatenft2, delegatenft3, ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `builders` in metaplex js library to get transaction builder and then convert it into transaction

```
const latestBlockhash = await   
 this.metaplex.connection.getLatestBlockhash();

const delegatenft1 = this.metaplex.tokens().builders().approveDelegateAuthority({
  mintAddress: nftMint2,
  //@ts-ignore
  delegateAuthority: this.publicKey,
}).toTransaction(latestBlockhash);

const delegatenft2 = this.metaplex.tokens().builders().approveDelegateAuthority({
  mintAddress: nftMint2,
  //@ts-ignore
  delegateAuthority: this.publicKey,
}).toTransaction(latestBlockhash);

const transaction = new Transaction().add(delegatenft1, delegatenft2, ...)
```